# Class Cast Exception on a simple code ( "==" override )

Tags: scala

This is a simplified code of what is happening in our application:

```
class First { def ==(first:First)= "mystring"}
case class Second(first:First)
Second(new First) == Second(new First)
```

this give:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean

I understand that I'm doing something wrong but I don't understand what.

**EDIT**

I have modified the code by changing:

```
class First { def ==(first:First)= true}
```

and now the error in REPL is:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : First(in object $iw)
 required: First(in object $iw)
       Second(new First) == Second(new First)
```

even more unexpected to me :\

**UPDATE** the second example is my fault. I changed class First in REPL interactively causing the strange result. Starting from scratch It works. Still the first one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Second` is a case class and it doesn't define or inherit custom `equals` method, the generated code for `Second#equals` should look like

```
override def equals(x: Any): Boolean = x match {
  case x: Second => first == x.first
  case _ => false
}
```

The `==` in the first branch will be your `==(First)`, not the usual `==(Any)`, because it's the more specific overload. So you "should" get a compilation error when declaring `Second`.

But from the stack trace it seems the compiler inserts a cast somewhere instead, either `(x match ...).asInstanceOf[Boolean]` or `(first == x.first).asInstanceOf[Boolean]`. To be honest, I can't really think of a reason why it would be written this way. But this makes `Second` compile and your later call fail.

Comment: This explanation doesn't seem to hold water: the compiler is actually smart enough to take the return type into account when it chooses the overloaded method to call. When I do this: `class Foo { def bar(x: Any): Boolean = false; def bar(x: String): String = x }`, then `val foo: Boolean = new Foo().bar("baz")` works properly, and returns `false`.

Comment: @Dima That's strange, if I'm reading http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution correctly it isn't supposed to work: both alternatives are applicable (that only depends on parameter types), and the return type only should matter for polymorphic types. Of course, I may be missing something since the rules are quite complicated.

Comment: @Dima Also, because the compiler inserts a cast (and we know it does because there wouldn't be a `ClassCastException` otherwise), then `first == x.first` itself doesn't have an expected type and so the compiler can't use it to choose the overload. That is, according to my explanation you need to try `val foo: Boolean = new Foo().bar("baz").asInstanceOf[Boolean]` instead.

Comment: It's seem others have spotted this too: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10539

Comment: I think the reason why the generated code of the case class behaves so strangely is that it gets generated during a compilation phase when typechecking is already underway, so it gets generated with a few  assumptions (e.g. `==` returning `Boolean`) and doesn't receive exactly the same treatment as the code that you can write yourself.

Comment: In erasure phase, it sees `stuff && ((this.x == other.x) && canEqual)`, has already determined `Boolean#&&`, then decides the result of `==` must be unboxed. It assumes the happy path instead of asserting that it makes no sense. (To confirm the previous correct conjectures.)

Answer (score 3):

The updated version (with `==` returning a Boolean) works for me.

The reason for your weird error is, probably, because you were trying it in REPL, and redefined the `First` class, but not `Second`.

REPL does some trickery to allow you redefine classes and variables, which is usually not possible in scala, so you basically end up having two versions of `First`, and your `Second` definition still references the older one, while the one you send to the constructor with `new First()` is the new one - thus the mismatch.

Just redefine the `Second` class again, and it will work.

There isn't much wrong with redefining `==` BTW, but it's just more common to override `equals` in these cases, which would have the same effect. The default implementation of `==` just calls `equals`, so, one problem with it is that someone downstream may override `equals` in one of your subclasses, and be stumped by the fact that it does not do what they expected.

Comment: Yes, the problem was caused by me changing It interactively  in REPL. Starting from scratch it works. thnks

Comment: Overriding equals instead of == works, but if == call equals why my example fail ?

Comment: Your example fails, because you override it to return a string while it needs to be a boolean

Comment: where I can find the definition of == to check this ? thanks

Comment: You can't it's a synthetic function: http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-synthetic-class-method-field/
I mean, maybe, you can, if you dig deep enough int compiler source ... but I'd just took my word for it if I were you ;)

Comment: Ok no implementation, but I was just curios about the *declaration*. (no IDE in this laptop, just REPL, so not easy to check by my self)

Comment: 1. This isn't redefining or overriding `==`, it's overloading. 2. Another problem with overriding `==` is that it no longer works when left-hand side is `null`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov (1) yes indeed! (I was wondering why it lets you do it without `override`, and missed the obvious reason). To override it properly, the parameter would need to be of type `Any`. (2) I don't think that's true: `null == new First` still works (and returns false).

Comment: @manorg see above comments about the declaration. The proper declaration would be `def == (other: Any): Boolean`. That would actually fail to compile in your case, because it'd catch the type mismatch, and also require that `override` keyword.

Comment: @Dima In `null == new First` the LHS type is `Null` and the standard `==` is used. Try `(null: First) == new First` instead.

Comment: really interesting conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Never override `==` operator, it's provided by the scala compiler, with the semantics similar to Object.equals method from java. This is the reason that it always returns boolean. So i assume that when you implemented your own operator scala tries to cast it's result to boolean.

Comment: I understand your answer but still I feel the result unexpected. In the real case we have already solved by using a different approach but still this exception surprise me. thanks

Comment: I'm testing it inline with repl to understand better but still I'm a bit buffled :)